# mpdf only certain styles being applied

Tags: php, css, laravel, mpdf

I seem to be having issues with [MPDF](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf) only loading certain styles in from my external stylesheet.

I'm building my PDF in my Laravel application like this

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'mode'           => 'utf-8',
    'margin_left'    => 0,
    'margin_right'   => 0,
    'margin_top'     => 50,
    'margin_bottom'  => 50,
    'margin_header'  => 0,
    'margin_footer'  => 0
]);
$mpdf->writeHTML(file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/css/pdf.css'), 1);
$mpdf->setHTMLHeader(view('layouts.partials.pdf.header')->render());
$mpdf->setHTMLFooter(view('layouts.partials.pdf.footer')->render());
$mpdf->WriteHTML(view('layouts.pdf')->render(), 2);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Which works fine, and is loading the HTML content fine.

For this issue, its not applying styles to my header properly. My header content looks like this

```
<header>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">
                <h1>My Title</h1>
            </td>
            <td class="right">
                @php
                //Get the image and convert to base 64
                $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/img/logo.png';
                $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $data = file_get_contents($path);
                $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
                @endphp
                <img src="{{$base64}}" alt="My Logo">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</header>
```

Which is loading the header perfect.

The content of the `pdf.css` file looks like this

```
header {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 100px;
}

header table tr .left {
  width: 70%;
}

header table tr .left h1 {
  color: white !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

header table tr .right {
  width: 30%;
}

header table tr .right img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

But its only applying certain styles from the `pdf.css` file! Its colouring the background of the header purple, but it will not change the `font-weight` or `color` of the `h1`.

Has anyone else experienced this before? Its like its picking and choosing which styles to apply, but because it renders a PDF, I cant use devtools to inspect!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just add td to you declarations like below

```css
header table tr td.left {
  width: 70%;
}

header table tr td.right {
  width: 30%;
}

header table tr td.left h1 {
  color: white !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

header table tr td.right img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Mhhh maybe there's a bug in MPDF, did you report it to the developer (there is a github repository)

Comment: Just tested a bit around. you need to give you h1 tag a class name (e.g. headline), then declare this class in you css file `.headline { color: white !important; font-weight: !important; }` then it should work